# what is the worst case time complexity of 5/n?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

> f(n)=5/n;

What is the BigOh of f(n)?

Answer (score 3):

The complexity does not grow with n, thus O(1)

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of computing `f(n)` is `O(1)`, and the space complexity is either `O(1)` or zero (depending on whether you count temporary registers as space)<sup>1</sup>.

If (hypothetically) `f(n)` was a cost function<sup>2</sup> for a computation, then its complexity class would be `O(1/n)`.  However, that makes no sense<sup>3</sup>.  How can you possibly have a cost function that tends towards zero as N tends towards infinity?  The cost will either be zero (for a null computation, or no space), or at least `1`. Costs are measured as measured as multiples of some indivisible unit; e.g. bits or bytes or instructions or clock cycles.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, this is an over-simplification.  The space required to represent `5/n` *precisely* as floating point number (in a given base) is infinite.  Therefore the time to compute that number representation *precisely* for those `n` values is also infinite.  However, that is not the way we normally write programs.  Computing the precise value of (for example) `5 / 3` in decimal is a fundamentally pointless exercise.</sup>

<sup>2 - For example, the time taken to perform the computation, the space taken by the computation ... or some other cost of performing a computation.</sup>

<sup>3 - It does make sense mathematically, according to the definition of Big Oh notation.</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by *the cost function*?